# Rolagem suave em conteudo de div

Tags: javascript, jquery, div, rolamento

Tenho um script que faz uma rolagem suave ao clicar no link com âncora. O problema é que ele rola a página toda. Preciso que ele role somente o conteúdo que está dentro de uma `div` específica e o resto da página permaneça fixa. Alguém pode ajudar?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$(".scrollSuave").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 00
    }, 500);
})
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        TÓPICOS DA AJUDA
    </a>
    <a href="#funcionamento" class="list-group-item scrollSuave">Opção 1</a>
    <a href="#cadastrar" class="list-group-item scrollSuave">Opçao 2</a>
</div>

<hr>
<!--  O CONTEUDO DESTA DIV QUE DEVE ROLAR O CLICAR NO LINK -->
<div class="col-lg-9">
<h4 id="funcionamento"><b>Opção 1</b></h4>
texto aqui

<h4 id="cadastrar"><b>Opção 1</b></h4>
texto aqui

</div>
```

Talvez eu não tenha conseguido explicar direito. Segue o print da pagina.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como vc quer rolar a div e as âncoras ao mesmo tempo? não entendi essa parte.

Answer (score 0):

Esta função faz o que pretende, basta ajustar os seletores aos elementos do seu código.

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
$(".scrollSuave").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

   var div_anc = $($.attr(this, 'href'));
   var div_anc_top = div_anc.offset().top;

   go_top = div_anc_top < 0 ? $("#div").scrollTop()-Math.abs(div_anc_top) : div_anc_top+$("#div").scrollTop();

    $("#div").animate({
        scrollTop: go_top-10 // 10 é o padding da div-mãe
    }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: block; width: 100px; background: #ddd; padding: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
   <a href="#funcionamento" class="scrollSuave">Opção 1</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#cadastrar" class="scrollSuave">Opção 2</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#teste" class="scrollSuave">Opção 3</a>
</div>

<div id="div" style="display: block; width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; background: yellow; padding: 10px; float: left;">
   <h4 id="funcionamento"><b>Opção 1</b></h4>
   Nullam dapibus orci nec ligula imperdiet feugiat. Quisque diam dui, tempus in nisi ac, lobortis dignissim eros. Vestibulum bibendum dapibus lectus, sed auctor erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis, magna a efficitur porta, tellus quam molestie felis, a porttitor diam nisi sed velit. Proin sed porta magna. Praesent efficitur rhoncus massa, quis luctus turpis fringilla in. Etiam ultricies lorem sed libero vehicula viverra. Sed dapibus porta pulvinar. Nam tempor, urna non commodo aliquam, lectus lacus consequat lacus, tincidunt ultricies odio lacus eu nulla. Pellentesque tincidunt tincidunt quam, sed malesuada risus feugiat at. Donec id ante vitae tortor malesuada ultricies. Suspendisse tempus tellus in nisl consectetur, ut ornare ipsum elementum.
   
   <h4 id="cadastrar"><b>Opção 2</b></h4>
   Nullam dapibus orci nec ligula imperdiet feugiat. Quisque diam dui, tempus in nisi ac, lobortis dignissim eros. Vestibulum bibendum dapibus lectus, sed auctor erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis, magna a efficitur porta, tellus quam molestie felis, a porttitor diam nisi sed velit. Proin sed porta magna. Praesent efficitur rhoncus massa, quis luctus turpis fringilla in. Etiam ultricies lorem sed libero vehicula viverra. Sed dapibus porta pulvinar. Nam tempor, urna non commodo aliquam, lectus lacus consequat lacus, tincidunt ultricies odio lacus eu nulla. Pellentesque tincidunt tincidunt quam, sed malesuada risus feugiat at. Donec id ante vitae tortor malesuada ultricies. Suspendisse tempus tellus in nisl consectetur, ut ornare ipsum elementum.

   <h4 id="teste"><b>Opção 3</b></h4>
   Nullam dapibus orci nec ligula imperdiet feugiat. Quisque diam dui, tempus in nisi ac, lobortis dignissim eros. Vestibulum bibendum dapibus lectus, sed auctor erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis, magna a efficitur porta, tellus quam molestie felis, a porttitor diam nisi sed velit. Proin sed porta magna. Praesent efficitur rhoncus massa, quis luctus turpis fringilla in. Etiam ultricies lorem sed libero vehicula viverra. Sed dapibus porta pulvinar. Nam tempor, urna non commodo aliquam, lectus lacus consequat lacus, tincidunt ultricies odio lacus eu nulla. Pellentesque tincidunt tincidunt quam, sed malesuada risus feugiat at. Donec id ante vitae tortor malesuada ultricies. Suspendisse tempus tellus in nisl consectetur, ut ornare ipsum elementum.
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu era isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: @ElsonLima Disponha! Se puder marcar ✔ a resposta para dar a pergunta como resolvida. Abs!